# How to monitor Mac OS X and determine cause of crash?

Tags: macos, mac, monitoring

I've got a Mac Mini running as a media server at home. Unfortunately, it tends to freeze, and it freeze while nobody's connected to it or watching at it. I'll turn the TV that it's hooked up to on and the display is garbage, the audio is white noise, and the Mac Mini is pretty warm to the touch.

How can I figure out what's causing this crash?

It'd be great to know *when* and *how* the server crashed. Is there any monitoring software I can use to report its temperature and process list every minute and other metrics? Is there a better solution than sending the output of `top` to a remote server every minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if this works.

1. I downloaded and paid for [Hardware Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/HardwareMonitor.html), which has a [command line tool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/216202/Docs-en/commandline.html) that prints information to stdout.
2. I created a secret [CGI script on a server that saves the POST body to a directory with a timestamp](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5118604).
3. I set up a cron job on the Mac Mini like this:

   */5 * * * * ( nice top -l1 -o CPU ; echo ; nice /Applications/HardwareMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/hwmonitor -f ) | curl --data-binary '@-' http://myserver.com/secret.py

Now I have process and temperature output. Let's see if that helps.